# Moving the Delete action from Web to Service Layer in MVC app - what should it return?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following method in my service layer:

```
public void DeleteOrder(int orderId)
        {
            var order = _db.Order.FirstOrDefault(c => c.OrderId == orderId);
            if (order == null)
            {
                // error handling
            }

            _db.Orders.Remove(order);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

What's the best practice in terms of returning something to a controller?  Currently Remove() action just calls this and redirects the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the service.

If the service layer is a soap service you should hanlde errors as faults and specify a fault contract.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx

If you are using a RESTFul service, I have always returned an Error object that indicates if the service operation was successful.

```
Class ErrorObject {

Bool IsOk

String ErrorMessage

String Trace

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of clients you will be interacting with. Since you are redirecting the client, it sounds like you aren't supporting AJAX clients at the moment.

In this case, the convention (started by Ruby on Rails) is to redirect after a successful result, and otherwise show the page corresponding to the action, with an error. Keep in mind, though, that most people using modern web apps expect to use javascript and asynchronous requests (AJAX). In this case, you probably want to return well-documented JSON that is one of two types:

```
{"error": {"code": ..., "fields": {"field1": "error message", "field2": "error message 2"}}
```

or some other JSON without the "error" set, if there is a success. Then, clients of all kinds would be able to hit your web service, including techniques such as JSONP or XHR with CORS.